# Principal directions bissect the asymptotic directions

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

How can one prove that at a hyperbolic point, the principal directions bissect the asymptotic directions?

Answer (score 3):

So for the principal directions say $e_1,e_2$ we have principal curvatures $k_1>0, k_2<0$. Then you can get $a,b \in \Bbb R $ such that $\frac{ b^2} {a^2} = - \frac{k_1}{k_2}$,then you have $ae_1+be_2$ and $ae_1-be_2$ as your candidates for asymptotic directions!

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**: Look up Euler's formula for normal curvature.

Comment: And? This is not really a hint, it doesn't say anything.

Comment: You're quite wrong. No, I'm not giving you a complete solution, especially as this is a standard homework problem. Yes, if you know the definitions, it will follow in one line from Euler's formula.

Comment: Is not a homework. Thank you anyway.